# Form not being created yet no errors are thrown in console Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, typescript2.0

I'm trying to pull my data from a variable and use it inside of a function to generate an Angular Form.  I bound both the Data variable and Form variable in the template just for the sake of seeing it as it builds but nothing is happening in the Forms variable while no errors are showing up in the console.

Here's my component

```
@Component({

    moduleId    : module.id,
    selector    : 'questionnaire-page',
    templateUrl : './questionnaire.component.html',
    providers   : [ QuestionService ]
})

export class QuestionnairePage implements OnInit, OnChanges{

    Data     : QuestionnaireBody= new QuestionnaireBody();
    Questionnaire: FormGroup;

    Submitted: boolean = false;

    constructor(private _qs: QuestionService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.Questionnaire = this.fb.group({ sections: this.fb.array([]) });
        this.buildQuestionnaire();
    }

    buildQuestionnaire(){
        let load = this.Data.sections;

        load.forEach( sect => {
            let grpA: new FromGroup = { name: sect.name, questions: this.fb.array([]) };
            let targetA = this.Questionnaire.sections;

            sect.questions.forEach(quest =>{
                let grpB: new FormGroup = { question: quest.question, id: quest.id, name: quest.name };
                let targetB = grpA.questions;

                targetB.addControl(grpB, new FormGroup() );
            });

            targetA.addControl(grpA, new FormGroup());
        });
    }



    ngOnInit() {

        this._qs.getData().subscribe( data => {this.Data = data});
    }

    ngOnChanges(){}

}
```

I haven't been bale to rationalize much to try other than swaping `this.fb.group()` for `new FormGroup()` in different places and applied combinations of my own custom classes such as `FormGroup<myClass>` or `myClass<FormGroup>` none of which made any difference or generated any errors.  My custom classes look like this

```
export class QuestionPrimative {
    question    : string = '';
    id          : string = '';
    name        : string = '';
    ctrlName?   : string = '';
    lowExtreme? : string = '';
    hiExtreme?  : string = '';
    template    : string = '';
}

export class Answer {
    answer      : string = '';
    id          : string = '';
    trigger?    : string = '';
    ctrlName?   : string = '';
}

export class QuestionBase extends QuestionPrimative {
    answers?    : Answer[] = [];
}

export class MicroQuestions {
    activate    : string    = '';
    questions   : Question[]= [];
}

export class Question extends QuestionBase {
    micros?     : MicroQuestions[] = [];
}

export class QuestionSection {
    name        : string    = '';
    questions   : Question[]= [];
}

export class QuestionnaireBody{
    sections: QuestionSection[] = [];
}
```

I seriously have no clue as to where to go from here.

Comment: Look, your `fb.array`s are empty

Comment: I'm trying to define them with `targetA.addControl(grpA, new FormGroup());` and `targetB.addControl(grpB, new FormGroup() );`